# how to change the clicked elements innerHTML in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a Html structure like

```
 <p>
      <a onclick="try {
        toggle_detail(&quot;additional&quot;);
        } catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert('toggle_detail(\&quot;additional\&quot;);'); throw e }; return false;" href="#">Show            </a>
 </p>

 <div id="additional">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
 </div>
```

I am writing a prototype to show the additional div on clicking show and hide on hide.

```
    $$("."+element_id).each(function(el){
        if(el.visible()){el.hide();

          // el.previous(0).innerHTML="Show";

    }
        else {el.show();
          //    el.previous(0).innerHTML="Hide";
    }
    });
```

where element_id = "additional"

How to update the innerhtml of the link to show/hide ?
I dont know how to update the clicked in link's innerHtml ..
Pls give suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `click` handler.

```
this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML == 'Show')?'Hide':'Show';
```

or add the caller as a parameter to your `toggle_detail` function

```
toggle_detail(this, &quot;additional&quot;);
```

and change the function to accept that extra parameter

```
function toggle_detail(clickButton, className){
    // do what you want with clickButton //
}
```

Also it makes not sense to alter the text inside the `each`. You should do it only once before or after the `each` call.

**Bonus:** Instead of `if(el.visible()) el.hide(); else el.show()` you can simply use `el.toggle()`.

Comment: actually i am generating the link by

Comment: <%= link_to_function "Show additional details", :class => 'underline' do |page|   page.call 'toggle_detail','additional'
 end -%>

Comment: how to send one more element as u said "this" along with the link

Comment: @Aruna, give more parameters to the function. You have an example in the my answer.